# Proxmox 8.0 reports "mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged"

Tags: proxmox

I am running a proxmox 8.0 server with the specifications below.
FYI, I updated this in proxmox 7.4.

```
CPU: Ryzen9 5950X
RAM: Samsung DDR4 64GB ECC-Unbuffered (32GB x 2)
m/b: tuf b450m-pro gaming
VGA: geforce GT 710
```

When I type dmesg, the error below is repeatedly reported.

```
[134486.139490] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[134797.441011] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[134797.441016] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[135108.739338] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[135108.739343] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

When I looked it up on the Internet, it said that I can check the details using the mcelog tool, but when I tried to use mcelog, the following is displayed, and I could not check the details.

```
mcelog: ERROR: AMD Processor family 25: mcelog does not support this processor. Please use the edac_mce_amd module instead.
CPU is unsupported
```

Similarly, the /var/log/mcelog file or directory does not exist.

I was informed somewhere that mcelog was deprecated and that I should now use rasdaemon.
So I enter the following command and it says there are no errors.

```
# ras-mc-ctl --summary
No Memory errors.

No PCIe AER errors.

No Extlog errors.

No MCE errors.

# ras-mc-ctl --errors
No Memory errors.

No PCIe AER errors.

No Extlog errors.

No MCE errors.
```

Is this a bug in proxmox 8.0? Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Does it create any problems except those messages?

Comment: I welcome you to serverfault.com. Proxmox has a great community support, -while business owners or serious business environment administratior have a subscription I would suggest that you take a look at the forum of proxmox, even the proxmox team is involved there.

Comment: Yes, there are no issues that I can see, at least outside of the logs for MCE. 

I'll also take a look at proxmox's forums.